What are the polynoms in $R_{n−1}[X]$ which are real-valued over the set of the n-ths roots of unity?
I am wondering what are the neccessary and sufficient conditions for a real circulant matrix $A= \begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} & \cdots & a_1 \\
a_1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_2 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-2} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & a_{n-1} \\
a_{n-1} & \cdots & a_2 & a_1 & a_0 
\end{pmatrix} \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $ to be diagonalisable in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.
One knows that $A=Q(J)$ with $J= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} $ and $Q=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kX^k$
$J$ is diagonalisable by $J=PDP^{-1}$ with $D=\text{diag}(\omega^0,\omega^1,\dots,\omega^{n-1})$ and $\omega=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}}$.
Hence
$$A =PQ(D)P^{-1}=P\text{diag}(Q(\omega^0),Q(\omega^1),\dots,Q(\omega^{n-1}))P^{-1}$$
Hence $A$ is diagonalisable in  $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.
If $A$ is diagonalisable over $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ then all $Q(\omega^i)$ are real and reciprocally if all the $Q(\omega^i)$ are real then $A$ is similar to a real diagonal matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and one can prove that they are also similar in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ so $A$ is diagonalisable in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.
Hence $A$ is diagonalisable  in $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $\ \forall i\in[\![0,n-1]\!],\quad Q(\omega^i)\in\mathbb{R}$
if and only if $Q$ is real-valued over $\mathbb{U_n}$
The question is then :
What are the  polynoms in $\boldsymbol{\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[X]}$ which are real-valued over $\boldsymbol{\mathbb{U}_n}$ set of the $n$-ths roots of unity ?
The polynoms   $Q =\alpha + \beta\displaystyle \prod_{\omega\in\mathbb{U_n}\backslash\mathbb{R}}(X-\omega)\in\mathbb{R}_{n-1}[X]$, $\quad \alpha,\beta \in\mathbb{R}$, are solutions because $Q(\omega)=\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for $\omega\in\mathbb{U_n}\backslash\mathbb{R}$ and $Q(\omega)\in\mathbb{R}$ if $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$.
Are there other solution polynoms  ?

Just a comment on notation: $\mathbb{U}_n$ I believe usually denotes the group of unipotent matrices. I've mostly seen $\mu_n$ for $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity.
You are of course free to choose any notation you want, but I don't think it is standard.

Thought it was, maybe  local notation.

There are a lot more. For example, when $n$ is even, $\beta=ax+b$ (instead of being just a real number) works because the degree of $\prod_{\omega\in\mathbb U_n\setminus\mathbb R}(x-\omega)$ is $n-2$, but there are still more.
First note that $f\in \mathbb R_{n-1}[x]$ is in bijection with $\overline{f} \in \mathbb R[x]/(x^n-1)$.
Let $x^n - 1 = \prod_{\omega\in\mathbb R}(x-\omega)\prod_{\omega\in \mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R}(x-\omega)=\prod_{\omega\in R}(x-\omega)\prod_{\omega\in S}(x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega})$. Note that $(x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega})$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R$. Here $R$ consists of all real $n$-th roots of unity, and $S\subset\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ such that for each pair of conjugate roots of $x^n-1$, it contains exactly one of them.
Note that $f(\omega)$ is real for all $\omega$, iff $f(\omega)=\overline{f(\omega)}=f(\overline{\omega})$ for all $\omega$. We show a simple lemma: for any real polynomial $f$, $f(\omega)=f(\overline{\omega})$ iff $\exists c\in\mathbb R, f\equiv c \mod (x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega})$. Indeed, through long division, $f(x) = q(x)(x-\omega)(x-\overline{\omega}) + r(x)$, where $\deg r(x)\le 1$. If $\deg r(x)=1$, then $r(x)$ is non-degenerate linear hence injective as a function from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$, therefore $f(\omega)=r(\omega)\not=r(\overline{\omega})=f(\overline{\omega})$. Thus $\deg(r(x))\le 1$.
By Chinese Remainder Theorem, $$\mathbb R[x]/(x^n-1)\simeq \prod_{\omega\in R} \mathbb R[x]/(x-\omega)\prod_{\omega\in S}\mathbb R[x]/(x^2-(\omega+\overline{\omega})x+1)\simeq \mathbb R^{|R|}\times\mathbb C^{|S|}$$
And according to the lemma, the image of those $f$ we want must be $\mathbb R^{|R|}\times\mathbb R^{|S|}$. Therefore, the dimension of the space of those polynomials as a real vector space is precisely $|R|+|S|$. Finally
$$\begin{cases} R=\{1\} , & |S|=\frac{n-1}{2},  & \dim = \frac{n+1}{2} & \text{ if } n \text{ is odd } \\ R=\{\pm1\}, & |S|=\frac{n-2}{2}, &\dim =\frac{n+2}{2} & \text{ if } n \text{ is even }\end{cases}$$
Following the proof of CRT, we can write down a basis for those polynomials, but I don't know how to do this explicitly.

Thank you, this CRT is perfect.
